# How to properly setup checkboxes to save to database using Rails 4 and simple_form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, checkbox, simple-form

I've created a form using the simple_form gem but can't get the values of the checkboxes to save. Radio buttons and select fields save perfectly.  I have found information on how to use the checkboxes with a model, but that's not what I'm trying to do. I'm passing the values as an array, but it looks like it needs a hash or something when I look at the html.  If I pass a hash I get the nasty red error page telling me my syntax is off.

I'm pretty fairly new to rails, so maybe my entire approach to this form is wrong and I should be using a model? I did create a helper for the language file but had different errors and decided to concentrate on trying to save to the database.

Any advice on how to setup the checkboxes correctly?

languages html output

```
<div class="control-group check_boxes optional program_languages">

<label class="check_boxes optional control-label">Languages</label>

<div class="controls">

<label class="checkbox">
<input class="check_boxes optional" id="program_languages_english" name="program[languages][]" type="checkbox" value="English" />English</label>

<label class="checkbox">
<input class="check_boxes optional" id="program_languages_portuguese" name="program[languages][]" type="checkbox" value="Portuguese" />Portuguese</label>

<label class="checkbox">
<input class="check_boxes optional" id="program_languages_italian" name="program[languages][]" type="checkbox" value="Italian" />Italian</label>

<label class="checkbox">
<input class="check_boxes optional" id="program_languages_russian" name="program[languages][]" type="checkbox" value="Russian" />Russian</label>

<label class="checkbox">
<input class="check_boxes optional" id="program_languages_korean" name="program[languages][]" type="checkbox" value="Korean" />Korean</label>

<label class="checkbox">
<input class="check_boxes optional" id="program_languages_german" name="program[languages][]" type="checkbox" value="German" />German</label>

<label class="checkbox">
<input class="check_boxes optional" id="program_languages_vietnamese" name="program[languages][]" type="checkbox" value="Vietnamese" />Vietnamese</label>

<label class="checkbox">
<input class="check_boxes optional" id="program_languages_tagalog" name="program[languages][]" type="checkbox" value="Tagalog" />Tagalog</label>

<label class="checkbox">
<input class="check_boxes optional" id="program_languages_french" name="program[languages][]" type="checkbox" value="French" />French</label>

<label class="checkbox">
<input class="check_boxes optional" id="program_languages_chinese" name="program[languages][]" type="checkbox" value="Chinese" />Chinese</label>

<label class="checkbox">
<input class="check_boxes optional" id="program_languages_spanish" name="program[languages][]" type="checkbox" value="Spanish" />Spanish</label>

<input name="program[languages][]" type="hidden" value="" />

</div>
```

programs_controller.rb

```
def index
   @programs = Program.all
end

def new
    @program= Program.new
end

def create
    @program = Program.new(program_params)
    if @program.save
        redirect_to @program
    else
        render action: "new"
    end
end

def edit
    @program = Program.find(params[:id])
end

def update
    @program = Program.find(params[:id])

    if @program.update_attributes(program_params)
        redirect_to programs_path
    else
        render action: "edit"
    end
end

def show
    @program = Program.find(params[:id])
  end

def destroy
    @program = Program.find(params[:id])
    @program.destroy
    redirect_to programs_url
  end

  def program_params
    params.require(:program).permit(:programName, :contactName, :email, :phone, :address, :city, :state, :zip, :ageGroup, :offline, :online, :founded, :website, :linkedin, :twitter, :facebook, :programsOffered, :languages, :servicesOffered, :communityServed)
  end
```

new.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for(@program, html: {class: 'form-horizontal' }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :programName %>
  <%= f.input :contactName %>
  <%= f.input :email, as: :email %>
  <%= f.input :phone, as: :tel %>
  <%= f.input :address %>
  <%= f.input :country, as: :country %>
  <%= f.input :state, collection: [ options_for_select(us_states)]  %>
  <%= f.input :city %>
  <%= f.input :zip %>
  <%= f.input :ageGroup, as: :check_boxes, collection: ['Any','Youth','Teen','Young Adult', 'Adult']  %>
  <%= f.input :offline, collection: ['Yes','No'],as: :radio_buttons %>
  <%= f.input :online, collection: ['Yes','No'], as: :radio_buttons %>
  <%= f.input :founded, collection: 1939..2014 %>
  <%= f.input :languages, collection: ['English','Portuguese','Italian','Russian','Korean','German','Vietnamese','Tagalog','French','Chinese','Spanish'], as: :check_boxes, include_blank: false %>
 <%= f.input :website, as: :url %>
  <%= f.input :linkedin, as: :url  %>
  <%= f.input :twitter, as: :url  %>
  <%= f.input :facebook, as: :url  %>
  <%= f.input :communityServed %>
  <%= f.input :servicesOffered %>
  <%= f.input :programsOffered %>
  <%= f.input :description %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
```

program.rb

```
  class Program < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :positions
  end
```

schema.rb

```
create_table "programs", force: true do |t|
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
t.string   "programName"
t.string   "contactName"
t.string   "email"
t.string   "phone"
t.string   "address"
t.string   "city"
t.string   "state"
t.string   "zip"
t.string   "ageGroup"
t.string   "offline"
t.string   "online"
t.string   "founded"
t.string   "website"
t.string   "linkedin"
t.string   "twitter"
t.string   "facebook"
t.string   "communityServed"
t.string   "servicesOffered"
t.string   "programsOffered"
t.text     "description"
t.string   "languages"
t.string   "country"
```

end

Answer (score 1):

In your controller, your're not properly setting the permitted parameters. From the strong parameters docs:

```
The permitted scalar types are String, Symbol, NilClass, Numeric, TrueClass, FalseClass, Date, Time, DateTime, StringIO, IO, ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile and Rack::Test::UploadedFile.

To declare that the value in params must be an array of permitted scalar values map the key to an empty array:

params.permit(:id => [])
```

So, in your case

```
params.require(:program).permit(..., :languages => [])
```

Take into account that this will save in your database a string representation of a ruby array of Strings.

You'll probably want to create a `Language` model and use a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship (or `has_many :through`).